# TypeScript types with Google Cloud Functions and Cloud Events

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, cloudevents

I'm using TypeScript to write some Cloud Functions (Gen 2) in GCP that are triggered by a PubSub message. Right now my code looks like this:

```
import { CloudEvent, cloudEvent } from "@google-cloud/functions-framework"


interface PubsubMessageSentData {
  message: {
    data: string
  }
}

cloudEvent("test", async (cloudEvent: CloudEvent<PubsubMessageSentData>) => {
  console.log("Data:", cloudEvent.data?.messgae.data)
})
```

I'm wondering if there's a type like `PubsubMessageSentData` defined by google somehwere so I don't have to rely on the interface I've written myself.

I'd expect there to be a type I can use to easily use as a type argument for `CloudEvent<>`

Answer (score 2):

I've found the types I'm looking for -

- protobufs are defined here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents
- TS types can be found here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents-nodejs